# Using "I wanted to know (I was wondering)" instead of "I want to know (I am wondering) "

Tags: phrase-usage

Last night while asking a question on ELL, I came up with another question. I had written this in my post:

> I **wanted to know** if there is a word or phrase in English for this kind
>   of friendship.

Then I thought since the tense of the second part of my sentence is present, I should change **wanted** to **want**.

I googled these terms and I found two different ideas about using past form (wanted) instead of present form (want).

One insists on tense agreement:

> - Want - for now,
>     Wanted for past time. Both are correct. You need to use them in a
>     context so that we can see. ([reference](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WantOrWanted/qklwx/post.htm))

Another says *"wanted to"* is more polite:

> - Both are correct, but we use wanted to show more politeness,
>     especially if your addressee has a higher status than you or is a
>     person that you respect. ([reference](https://www.englishforums.com/English/WantOrWanted/qklwx/post.htm))

And also this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80410/i-was-wondering-vs-i-am-wondering-vs-i-wonder) about "I am/was wondering":

> While technically the three phrases differ in tense, they all have the
>   same meaning. I'd suspect that "I was wondering" is used most often,
>   followed by "I wonder". "I am wondering" would probably be reserved
>   for cases where you're really perplexed because it suggests the wonder
>   continued over a longer period of time.

Since there are different ideas about this, I'm a little confused. My question is if we can use "I wanted to know (I was wondering)" instead of "I want to know (I am wondering)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“I wanted to know (I was wondering)” is an example of being **indirect for politeness**.  Just as you said, if you are talking to a respected person, or a stranger, this is an appropriate way to speak or write.   Some people say it is *too* indirect and an obsolete way to speak, but this is not universal.

“I **would like** to know” is another way to convey politeness without using the past tense.

“**I am wondering**” is perfectly acceptable in today’s American English as a way to begin asking a question, even to a respected person.

“**I want to know**” or “**I need to know**” is very direct— it’s grammatically correct but it may not be socially correct.  It would be appropriate speaking to a close friend, or in writing if there is not a person being addressed. (“I want to know if the universe is expanding.”)